# Python extract string from a string

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and I don't know how to extract strings from a bigger string. I have a string:

```
s = '''
    GLOBAL_VAR

    (*variables from PLC*)

    (*Inputs*)
    A0_var1:    BOOL;
    A0_var2:    BOOL;
    A0_var3:    BOOL;

    (*Outputs*)
    A2_var4:    BOOL;
    A2_var5:    BOOL;
    A2_var6:    BOOL;

    END_GLOBAL_VAR
    '''
```

How to extract variable names to get something like:

```
["A0_var1", "A0_var2", "A0_var3", "A2_var4", "A2_var5", "A2_var6"]
```

Comment: Please include your attempt in your question. IMHO ``regex`` is overkill for this task, a loop and a simple ``split`` will suffice once you detect the "pattern".

Comment: this is a very basic question, you should be able to easily go through a tutorial and work this out, might not be a good fit for stackoverflow

Comment: `[w[:-1] for w in s.split() if w.endswith(':')]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) from the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module, along with the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) method:

```
from re import findall

s = '''
    GLOBAL_VAR

    (*variables from PLC*)

    (*Inputs*)
    A0_var1:    BOOL;
    A0_var2:    BOOL;
    A0_var3:    BOOL;

    (*Outputs*)
    A2_var4:    BOOL;
    A2_var5:    BOOL;
    A2_var6:    BOOL;

    END_GLOBAL_VAR
    '''

a = list(filter(None, findall('[^ ]*?(?=\:)', s)))

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['A0_var1', 'A0_var2', 'A0_var3', 'A2_var4', 'A2_var5', 'A2_var6']
```